# Angularjs ng-submit function is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a ng-template in my html view and there is a form inside the ng-template.So i need to submit form data through the form and i'm using ng-submit to do that.But when i click on submit button nothing happens.Other data binding works with text fields in the form using ng-model with my controller.Following is my html code.

```
   <script type="text/ng-template" id="updatetemplate">
   <div class="box box-primary">
   <div class="box-header with-border">
   <h3 class="box-title">Update</h3>
   </div>
   <!-- /.box-header -->
   <!-- form start -->
   <form name="update_form" ng-submit="updateUser(ngDialogData.id,  ngDialogData.currentname, ngDialogData.currentroleid)">
   <div class="box-body">
   <div class="form-group">
   <input type="hidden" name="userid" ng-model="ngDialogData.id"   class="form-control">
   <label>Name</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" ng-  model="ngDialogData.currentname" placeholder="Enter name">
   <p></p>
   <label>User role</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" name="roleid" ng-model="ngDialogData.currentroleid" placeholder="Enter name">
   </select>

   </div>

   </div>
   <!-- /.box-body -->

   <div class="box-footer">
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="updatebutton">Update</button>
   </div>
   </form>
   </div>
   <!-- /.box -->
   </script>
```

Comment: can you share your controller code pls

Comment: `ng-  model="ngDialogData.currentname"` remove blank space

Comment: @Korte - Actually that blank space not exists in my code.When i'm copying code here that has added.So no issue with that.

Comment: @Jax - Ok, i will share the relevant function code if you need.This is one of my office projects and therefore i can't share complete code.But i'm sure controller is working since data binding works fine with scope values.Sorry about that.

Comment: without relevant code you are not likely to get much help, good luck!

Comment: @Jax - ok, i know that.But as i said i can put my function not the whole controller.I think it is sufficient.Anyway thanks for your enthusiasm.Will see!!

Comment: @CodeCanyon did you checked my answer ?

Answer (score 0):

**Some code correction need to be made :**

- remove blank space from `ng- model`.
- instead of passing each `ng-model` into the `updateUser` function. just pass the whole `ngDialogData` object.
- There is one invalid `</select>` tag in the form. remove that.

**Working fiddle :** https://jsfiddle.net/d8ye0sbz/